# Is there a way to query the runtime for argv in java?

Tags: java, argv

Is there a way to query the runtime for argv in java? Like sys.argv in python.

Yes I realize in java you usually just pass args from main. I realize this may not be a good idea in practice. I'm porting a lib from python that has a default argument of sys.argv. I may decide to  include or exclude it in the end.

Comment: Outside of Java and therefore unportably, some particular systems may provide access, for example on linux, you can read /proc/self/cmdline as if it were a text file, which may, depending on the jvm and means of invocation, have the information you seek.

Comment: yes and on windows you can query wmi Win32_Process interface for  CommandLine

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to get hold of the `main(String[])` arguments by any other means.

(I thought it might be possible using the `RuntimeMXBean` API.  There is a method on that API called `getInputArguments()` but the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/management/RuntimeMXBean.html#getInputArguments%28%29) explicitly says that the arguments passed to `main(...)` are not included.)

Answer (score -1):

Yes, I think there is a somewhat klunky way to do that.  I have put some code [here](http://ideone.com/dauVk).

Comment: You should have posted the code in your answer, but regardless it does not seem to solve the problem posed by the question - your example doesn't access the arguments, and appears to work only by being main itself, which is what the question seeks an *alternative* to.